# Will pthread_detach manage my memory for me?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, malloc, pthreads

Suppose I have the following code:

```
while(TRUE) {
  pthread_t *thread = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_create(thread, NULL, someFunction, someArgument);
  pthread_detach(*thread);
  sleep(10);
}
```

Will the detached thread free the memory allocated by malloc, or is that something I now have to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. **pthread_create()** has no way of knowing that the **thread** pointer passed to it was dynamically allocated. pthreads doesn't use this value internally; it simply returns the new thread id to the caller. You don't need to dynamically allocate that value; you can pass the address of a local variable instead:

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, someFunction, someArgument);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to free the memory yourself.  It would be preferable to simply allocate the pthread_t variable on the stack as opposed to the heap.

Comment: OP's problem is thinking that because `pthread_create` takes a `pthread_t` argument, you need a pointer variable to pass. This is a classic mistake of beginning C programmers - declaring pointer variables to use as arguments rather than passing `&foo`.